# What is wrong with php strtotime

Tags: php

```
$d = '20-04-2001';
echo date('Y-m-d',strtotime($d));

output 2025-09-22
```

it think it might version problem
currently using PHP Version 4.4.6

Comment: From the php docu: "Dates in the m/d/y or d-m-y formats are disambiguated by looking at the separator between the various components: if the separator is a slash (/), then the American m/d/y is assumed; whereas if the separator is a dash (-) or a dot (.), then the European d-m-y format is assumed." so his code seems to be correct.

Comment: Still using PHP 4 ? You'd better come back to modern age.

Comment: Various odd results are returned from PHP versions below v5.1.2. See [this fiddle](http://3v4l.org/Tn18r2)

Answer (score 0):

strtotime parse date in specific formats only. You can see http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php